# raisecom get vlan macs by snmp

Tags: vlan, snmp, mac-address

I'm, trying to get `mac` addresses from switches in a network. For that i'm using snmp calls with these oids: (like in [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_tech_note09186a00801576ff.shtml) manual) `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.1`, `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2`. But i have a problem with Raisecom ISCOM device: it seems not to support this oids.

Another problem is that Raisecom doesn't answer for `snmp -c community@vlan...` prompt - only without `vlan`.

So, my question is: how can i get this mac addresses and how to manage with vlans?

Answer (score 1):

try this small bash script to get mac - port - vlan
$1 - is community
$2 - is ip address/hostname

```
#!/bin/bash
snmpwalk -Cc  -Onq -v 2c -c $1 $2 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2 |(
 while read line ; do 
echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F. '{printf("%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\t",$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21)}'
echo $line | awk '{printf("%u\t",$2)}' 
echo $line | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F. '{print $15}'
done)
exit 0
```